# Reading Data from Header in a flat file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have pipe delineated flat file that SSIS is reading in. This flat file has 7 header rows. There is an option to skip (n) number of header rows, but the problem is, is that I need to have the ability to retrieve data from these rows as well.

What is the best way of retrieving this this information to be used later in data flow?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try.

If there is a field that denotes the header you can read in all the data then use a conditional split to split out the header records from the data.

Or you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476536/how-do-i-retrieve-only-the-top-x-rows-from-a-flatfile-in-ssis/1477143#1477143).

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, you could always use Script Component of type Source.